# A strict directed colimit of Hausdorff locally-convex spaces that is not Hausdorff

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

We work in the category of locally-convex spaces (morphisms are the continuous linear maps).  Let $\Lambda$ be a directed set, for every $\lambda \in \Lambda$ let $V_{\lambda}$ be a locally-convex space, and for $\lambda _1\leq \lambda _2$ let $\iota _{\lambda _2,\lambda _1}\colon V_{\lambda _1}\rightarrow V_{\lambda _2}$ be a continuous linear map.  This directed diagram is *strict* iff each $\iota _{\lambda _2,\lambda _1}$ is an embedding, that is, a homeomorphism onto its image.

If $\Lambda =\mathbb{N}$ and each $V_{\lambda}$ is Hausdorff, then $\operatorname{colim}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}V_m$ is likewise Hausdorff (see, for example, II.6.4 in Schaefer's *Topological Vector Spaces*).  What about if the directed colimit is not sequential (i.e. has index set $\mathbb{N}$)?

> If $\operatorname{colim}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}V_{\lambda}$ is a strict directed colimit of Hausdorff locally-convex spaces, must it be Hausdorff?

If there is a counter-example (and I suspect there is), the nicer one can make the $V_{\lambda}$s, the better (for example, to find an analogous counter-example for completeness, you can take them to be Banach spaces); but of course I would be happy to find any such counter-example =)

Comment: It is important to specify in which category do you take this colimit: the category of topological spaces, of topological groups, of linear topological spaces, of locally convex spaces? Those direct colimits all will have different topologies. In the category of topological groups (and topological linear spaces) the Hausdorff property is equivalent to the separation axiom $T_1$ (=all singleton are closed), which is preserved by direct limits (even in the category of topological spaces and their continuous maps).

Comment: @TarasBanakh. I intended to take all colimits in the category of locally-convex spaces.  I have edited the question for clarity =)

Comment: It seems that the answer to your question is affirmative and can be obtained by transfinite induction on the cardinality of the index set $\Lambda$. This allows us to replace $\Lambda$ by a well-ordered set. The inductive step will use the Hahn-Banach Theorem at successor ordinals and the definition of the direct colimit at limit ordinals. Am I right?

Comment: I have found that this question (in the non-strict version) has been asked on MathOverFlow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221476/do-hausdorff-locally-convex-inductive-limits-always-exist?rq=1) and was answered negatively. Nonetheless I hope that the strict version has an affirmative answer.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I don't quite understand your comment (which nevertheless sounds interesting). It seems somehow that you argue with the (projective) limit of the duals and that you can conclude surjectivity of $\lim V_\lambda' \to V_\alpha'$ from the surjectivity of all $V_\lambda' \to V_\alpha'$. According to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158761/tietzes-extension-theorem-for-compact-subspaces this is not possible (for general projective limits).

Comment: The dual situation referred to above makes me feel that the answer to your question should be negative.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth It seems that you are absolutely right: just take a countable second countable connected Hausdorff space $X$  (for example, the Bing space or the Golomb space)  and for every compact subset $K\subset X$, consider the dual Banach space $C(K)^*$, endowed with the  weak* topology. Then the direct spectrum $\{C(K)^*:K\subset X\}$ has non-Hausdorff co-limit as any two distinct Dirac measures on $X$ cannot be separated by a continuous functional (as it determines a non-trivial continuous function on $X$). This is very surprising and counterintuitive!

Comment: @TarasBanakh Indeed.  It seems well-known that the *strict* colimit of a *sequence* of locally-convex Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff.  I was wondering if both hypotheses (strict and sequential) are necessary.  For the strict hypothesis, I found the answer you linked to; however, for the sequential hypothesis, I was not able to find a counter-example that demonstrated that the colimit being sequential was necessary.

Comment: @Jonathan-Gleason By sequential, you understand that the directed set has countable cofinality. Right? A counterexample of a strict inductive limit for a directed set of uncountable cofinality (namely the family of compact subsets of a connected Hausdorff countable secord countable space)  was gien by Jochen Wengenroth in his comment (see also my comment explaining his comment, at least at my level of understanding his idea).

Comment: @TarasBanakh.  Actually, by "sequential" I meant to say that the indexing category is literally equal to $\mathbb{N}$ (it's just simply more convenient to say "sequential" than "with index category $\mathbb{N}$").  Of course, being equal to $\mathbb{N}$ is itself not essential and, as you say, this should work as long as the directed set has countable cofinality (though not more generally in view of the above counter-example).

Comment: @JonathanGleason In the wonderful book "Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces" by Pérez Carreras, Bonet you can find the following Observation 8.1.2(b): an inductive sequence of normed spaces $X_n$ with the same underlying linear space $X_n = X$ (the space of polynomials $p$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $p(0) = 0$). The norms on $X$ are defined by $\lVert p \rVert_n := \sup_{x \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]} |p(x)|$ and the locally convex inductive limit topology (on $X$) turns out to be trivial.